# Values not getting loaded from property file in JUnit

Tags: junit, junit4

This is my test file and I am not able to inject values from property file

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = VersionResourceImplTest.myProp.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"ra.bank.app.version=TestVersion"})
public class VersionResourceImplTest {

    @Value("${ra.bank.app.version}")
    private String applicationVersion;

    @Test
    public void testVersion() {
        Assert.assertEquals("TestVersion", applicationVersion);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class myProp{
        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesResolver()
        {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }
    }
}
```

Getting error: Failed tests:

```
VersionResourceImplTest.testVersion:36 expected:<TestVersion> but was:<null>
Not able to fetch values from property file
```

Comment: Your test doesn't use RunWith(SpringRunner.class), so all the Spring annotations are simply ignored.

Comment: yeah...it worked for me ...thanks a LOT :)